# defining onclick navigation using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I'm trying to do onClick function, that will redirect the user after inputing specific text to searched page... When in function definition I use only simple if... else than everything is all right. Problem appears when I try to use multiple else if.

```
<input id="naszInput"></input>
<button onclick="searchMe();">Search</button>
```

and function definition:

```
<script>
function searchMe () {

if ($("#naszInput").val().toLowerCase() == "zara")
{
    window.location.href = 'zara.html';
}

    else if ($("#naszInput").val().toLowerCase() == "orsay")
{
    window.location.href = 'orsay.html';
}

else
{
    $("#naszLabel").text("cannot find!");
}
}
</script>
```

Any ideas why is it that?
And this is what Chrome console tells me about this error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: searchMe is not defined app.html:1
onclick

Comment: You must define the function before defining the button that calls it. Try placing your script block in the `header`.

Comment: that's not a reason, function definition is in header, calling function is in body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the onclick attribute on the button, and add an id attribute which can be used to hook up a click event. Also, I would suggest moving your javascript into an external file.

```
<button id="btnSearch">Search</button>


<script>
function searchMe () {

if ($("#naszInput").val().toLowerCase() == "zara")
{
    window.location.href = 'zara.html';
}

    else if ($("#naszInput").val().toLowerCase() == "orsay")
{
    window.location.href = 'orsay.html';
}

else
{
    $("#naszLabel").text("cannot find!");
}
}
    $(function(){
      $('#btnSearch').click(searchMe);

    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, it helped a lot. I changed button to id and now only cannot find didn't work, but zara and orsay normally loads :)

Comment: Hah, I'm quite a noob, but do you know why this else "cannot find" didnt work? i tried with adding additional else if and they work, but this last else didnt...

Comment: Do you have an element on the page with an id equal to "naszLabel"?

Comment: Hah, yes, that's that. I deleted label with this id, one more time thanks :)